# "topic name cannot be unicode" error

Tags: rospy, rosbridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I was trying to use rosbridge version 2.0 under ROS diamondback distro. I have succesfully checked it out from git repository and compiled, as stated in rosbridge.org web page. The server also runs succesfully, as I get this message:

```
[INFO] [WallTime: 1355124066.345832] Rosbridge server started on port 9090
```

The problem comes when I try to send a subscription request as a JSON formatted string, following the example at http://rosbridge.org/doku.php?id=wiki:getting_started. I get this error:

```
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1355124428.555009] [Client 0] subscribe: topic name cannot be unicode
```

Looking around I found that this error comes from topic implementation of rospy. However, I do not know how to overcome this error. Is there any way to explicitly force the topic name to be ascii instead of unicode in a straightforward way? Any help is appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50051/%22topic-name-cannot-be-unicode%22-error/) by [marija](https://answers.ros.org/users/2428/marija/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2012-12-09

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [odestcj](https://answers.ros.org/users/313/odestcj/) on 2013-02-01**:
Thanks for working through this issue.  A clarification is in order: it is highly recommended to use rosbridge v2 for the *current* distribution of ROS.  rosbridge v1 is the best option for diamondback and electric, v2 for fuerte, groovy, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

FYI - Although as stated in rosbridge.org it is highly recommended that you use version 2.0 of the rosbridge protocol, I tried rosbridge v1.0 under diamondback and it worked. So at this moment, it is the only way for me to use diamondback + rosbridge.

---

Originally posted by [marija](https://answers.ros.org/users/2428/marija/) with karma: 36 on 2012-12-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0